# Cannot map resources for my Spring Maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, spring-mvc

I can't map my static resources like css and js files in my Spring application built in Maven.

I already followed the guidelines offered related to this question but still it fetches me 404 status for my resources.

I have below directory list

```
/src/main/webapp/
\
 WEB-INF
        \
         views
         applicationContext.xml
         dispatcherServlet.xml
         web.xml
 resources
         \
          themes
               \
                bootstrap
                        \
                         css (bootstrap.min.css is inside)
                         js  (bootstrap.min.js is inside)
```

I have the mvc:resource mapping in my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/themes/bootstrap/"/>
```

Below is my LoginPage.jsp file.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <spring:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" var="loginCss" />
    <spring:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js" var="loginJs" />

    <link href="${loginCss}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="${loginJs}"></script>
...
</html>
```

After inspection it is fetching to below URL with 404 status:

```
http://localhost:8080/{project-name}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css 
http://localhost:8080/{project-name}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.js
```

Comment: What if you call `http://localhost:8080/{project-name}/css/bootstrap.min.css` ?

Comment: @StanislavL still not working, does xml mapping for resources is still applicable in Spring 4.3.8 version?

Comment: I have accessed the resource file with below link:

`http://localhost:8080/{project-name}/resources/themes/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`

But, is it still not functioning since the mapping as per **mvc:resources** is stated to **_"/resources/*"_**?

Answer (score 0):

Check the servlet-mapping on web.xml.

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**Edit:**

Add the below servlet-mapping to your web.xml

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/**</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: my servlet mapping is below:

`<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`

Comment: try to add another servlet-mapping to resources folder,<br/> `  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/**</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>`